# Non normal independent and dependent variable - GLM

Tags: multiple-regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, normality-assumption

I use variables, independent as well as dependent, which are inherently not normaly distributed. Exept a few "extremist", nobody score very above the mean on these scale, which are validated on peer reviews journals and widely used (e.g. rape myths scale).

I ran an experiment with two experimental condition, measure of two non normal IV, and measure of two non normal outcomes.
As a rookie I am, i ran general linear model to observe principle and interaction effect. Found significative results but with wide 95%IC.
I then realized that none of this measures were normally distributed.

I sometimes read that non normality, weather it be on IV or DV, is not mandatory to run GLM. However i also read the opposite which suggest to switch to non parametric (impossible) or to convert variables into log or others.

What is your opinion (and sources) about this please ?
I admit i feel a bit terrified to see my project destroy because of systematic non normal measures...
And i cant find answers on published papers because almost all use these variables in correlational studies using structural equation model allowing to correct for non normality.

EDIT :
Here the assumptions check from the GLM for IV 1 :
Levene : p=.073
Kolmogorov =.258
Shapiro p=.002

[image]

[image]

[image]

For IV 2 :
Levene p=.025
Kolmogorov p<.001
Shapiro p<.001

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Normality does not matter for the independent ($x$) variables. For the dependent ($y$) variable, normality can matter, but that is for the error term or conditional distribution, not of the distribution of all $y$ values together. However, if you have reason to suspect a different kind of conditional distribution, maybe a different GLM family could be appropriate. Perhaps you can say more about the problem you are trying to solve and the data you have so we can guide you to good statistical methods.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your welcome and your answer. Indeed I read about normality of residuals (if it's what you are talking about) but i am unable to interpret results. Here are results :   for the first outcome, output show Levene test p=.073 ; Kolmogorov-Smirnov p=.258 ; Shapiro p=.002. QQplot seem correct and histogram too. Residual-predicted scatterplot just look like a rather round mass

Comment: For the 2nd outcome, answer are all from 1 to 3 (on a 7 scale), which is logical given what it measure. Levene, Kolmogorov and Shapiro all significant. Qqplot look like someone drunk having hard time to walk on a straight line, histogram not normal, and residual predicted scatterplot have 4 straight lines on different level, above each other

Comment: I edited my initial post to show graphs if needed. The thing is that i will have this type of GLM assumptions in every studies..